# Ubuntu 21.10 with KDE Plasma does not shut down

Tags: kde, shutdown, 21.10, plasma

This is what I did:

1.) Clicked on the Start menu

2.) Clicked on the shut down button

3.) It asks me to confirm shut down while giving other options like restart, sleep, logout etc, so I click shut down.

4.) Taskbar disappears.

5.) The PC freezes. I can see the desktop icons, my wallpaper, etc. The cursor and does not work. I even kept my computer in this state for 9 hours waiting for it to shut down, but it didn't. I always need to force shutdown by holding the power on button for 5 seconds or so.

I an running Ubuntu 21.10.

Here is a video of the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gY5Sfi-18lNyYa3WOn22ygFAPJLf1g9H/view?usp=sharing

Shut down now works fine. I just have to sign out first, then click power off from the sign out screen.

Comment: If the original poster (OP) posts an update, I might be able to give an answer that is a permanent solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As OP (original poster) said, a fix is to:

1. Sign out first
2. Then click “Power Off” from the “Sign Out” menu.

Also try typing `shutdown now` in the terminal (konsole). See if that works.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and can verify the solution works. What's really odd is that this didn't happen three days ago when I did a clean install. The only major change since then is that I set up a google remote desktop. Could that have had an effect?